# Take $X=F_{1}\cup F_{2}$, then the function $f$ is continuous iff $f|_{F_{1}}=F_{1}\rightarrow Y$ and $f|_{F_{2}}=F_{2}\rightarrow Y$ are continuous.

Tags: general-topology

Recently I was reading some all notes of my differential geometry class and I stumbled with this unproven statement:

> Suppose $X=F_{1}\cup F_{2}$ where $F_{1}$ and $F_{2}$ are closed subsets and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a map. then  $f$ is continuous iff $f|_{F_{1}}=F_{1}\rightarrow Y$ and $f|_{F_{2}}=F_{2}\rightarrow Y$ are continuous.

I feel that it is not difficult to prove, but I have been unable to do it, maybe its because it has been long since I had my classes in differential geometry. In reality I want to prove the statement just for competition sake. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: This is known as "the pasting lemma."

Comment: Than you very much, maybe that is why it was never demonstrated in class.

Comment: Perhaps the following could help you start your proof: A map is continuous if and only if preimages of closed sets are closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completition sake, I leave the answer:

As mentioned in the comments this is the Pasting Lemma.

Take $U$ a closed subset of $Y$.

Now, the set $(f|_{F_{1}})^{-1}(U)$ is closed in $F_{1}$ because $f|_{F_{1}}$ is continuous, and therefore $(f|_{F_{1}})^{-1}(U)$ is closed in $X$, because a closed subset of a closed subset of $F_{1}$ is a closed subset of $X$.

With the same argument we can see that $(f|_{F_{2}})^{-1}(U)$ is closed in X.

Therefore $f^{-1}(U)=(f|_{F_{1}})(U)\cup(f|_{F_{2}})(U)$ is closed in $X$.